# how to set width and height of a form in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I set the width and height of a form in Delphi 7? The form contains different types of controls on it. I need to set the main form size to 127x263. It should change programmatically
in a button click.

Comment: please make sure you always include the generic delphi tag since not so many people check the delphi-7 tag. I added it this time but for future questions please remember this - you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: ok. I will do so in future, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like so:

```
MainForm.Width := 127;
MainForm.Height := 263;
```

Or perhaps you want to set the client area to those dimensions:

```
MainForm.ClientWidth := 127;
MainForm.ClientHeight := 263;
```

Of course, you most commonly set these properties in the Object Inspector at design time and then they are written to your form's .dfm file.

If you want such a change to occur on a button click add a handler for the button click that looks like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Width := 127;
  Height := 263;
end;
```

In this last excerpt you don't need to specify the `MainForm` object instance because the event handler is a member of the `TMainForm` class and so the `Self` is implicit.

If you wish to follow Ulrich Gerhardt's advice (see comment) and use `SetBounds` then you would write:

```
SetBounds(Left, Top, 127, 263);
```

Finally, if your form has `Scaled = True` then you need to deal with font scaling. Hard coded pixel dimensions like this will not be appropriate for machines with font scaling set to a different value from your machine.

Comment: Instead of changing Width and Height individually, I'd use SetBounds to minimize updates.

Comment: Setting `ClientHeight` and `ClientWidth` programmatically won't affect the form if `AutoSize` is set to true.